# Get latest date action from each employee

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm doing some query where I need to get the data of how many actions passed but i just need to count the latest action of each employee and disregard the other action since its not the latest date.

Table 1

| c_id | p_id | d_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 82 | 22 | 30 |
| 83 | 22 | 30 |

Table 2

| src_id | c_id | int_date | phase | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 82 | 11-28-2022 | Action 1 | passed |
| 2 | 83 | 11-29-2022 | Action 1 | passed |
| 3 | 83 | 11-29-2022 | Action 2 | passed |
| 4 | 82 | 11-30-2022 | Action 2 | passed |
| 5 | 83 | 12-1-2022 | Action 3 | passed |

Expected output:

| Phase | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Action 2 | 1 |
| Action 3 | 1 |

Output that i received

| Phase | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Action 1 | 2 |
| Action 2 | 2 |
| Action 3 | 1 |

So far this is my query code:

```
SELECT src.phase as name1, COUNT(src.phase) as count_status, MAX(src.int_date) as dates
FROM int_scores src, cand_info c
WHERE c.d_id = 30 AND c.p_id = 22 AND c.c_id = src.c_id
GROUP BY name1 ORDER BY name1
```

Comment: There are no `phase` and `int_date` columns in either table. Why do you change the names in the sample tables from the query?

Comment: @Barmar sorry about that. i just changed it. the phase is for the action before and int_date is the date.